# SDN4 - What are recommended strategies for doing auditing?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, auditing, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.RC1 to build a CRUD application and am interested in auditing EACH and EVERY operation performed on my nodes and relationships, e.g. CRUD.  What are some general strategies for accomplishing this?

I am aware of the event listeners but are they they the best option available for capturing audit information?  My impression is that Neo4j may not be an inherently suitable store for this information - is another DB typically recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with the information, how do you want to access / query it. How frequently do you need to access it etc.

Easiest would be just to dump it to an audit-log file.

Otherwise any database should be able to store this kind of simple structured records.